# Laravel how to get id parameter in model relation?

Tags: laravel

I've got a query to get messages:

```
public function getMessagesFor($id)
{
   $messages = Message::where(function($q) use ($id) {
        $q->where('from', auth()->id());
        $q->where('to', $id);
    })->orWhere(function($q) use ($id) {
        $q->where('from', $id);
        $q->where('to', auth()->id());
    })->get();
}
```

and this logic works as it should, no errors all is ok. Now I want to get messages directly via model relatioship with other user (not authenticated one)

so in User model I wrote:

```
public function messages()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Message::class, 'to', 'id')
    ->where('messages.from', auth()->id());
 }
```

And this basically gives the same result as first where clause in getMessages function. This relatioship works ok.

The problem is that I don't know how to code the second part of where clause. I don't have access to `$id` in my model so how should I approach to this? Any ideas how to code it?

edit: message migration:

```
    Schema::create('messages', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('from')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('to')->unsigned();
        $table->boolean('read')->default(false);
        $table->integer('offer_id')->nullable();
        $table->mediumText('body')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Comment: To make sure I'm understanding your question -- in both cases, you're query is trying to get Messages with an id that is in one of two ranges or lists of IDs? Is that right?

Comment: I don't get your question, two ranges of lists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I think the problem is the model relationship (user) is already set to get message where the user is the message reciever(to),

```
$this->hasMany(Message::class, 'to', 'id')
```

so you need to define another relationship to get messages where the user is the sender (from), so you have this

```
//user is reciever
public function sentMessages() {
    return $this->hasMany(Message::class, 'to', 'id')
    ->where('messages.from', auth()->id()); }

//user is sender
public function recievedMessages() {
    return $this->hasMany(Message::class, 'from', 'id')
    ->where('messages.to', auth()->id()); }
```

Anyway I advise you go with your first approach.

Okay, so adding your final soultion to get messages

```
//get all messages with
$this->sentMessages->merge($this->recievedMessages)
```

Comment: It seems not to be a good practice, maybe I'll look for other solution for now...

Comment: and gives an error:  `"message": "array_merge(): Argument #1 is not an array",`

Comment: I'm trying to make sth like: `return $this->hasMany(Message::where([['messages.from', auth()->id()], ['messages.to', 'id']]));` but even this throws: `"message": "Too few arguments to function Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Builder::__construct(), 0 passed in C:\\www2\\medpraca2\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Concerns\\HasRelationships.php on line 656 and exactly 1 expected",`

Comment: that was a good idea to split the functions in the model. I merged them outside the model using `$this->sentMessages->merge($this->recievedMessages)` and I finally works. You may update this answer with this